# My serverless template returns "public subnet group found error"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, subnet, vpc

My problem is that although I have two different public subnet in AWS VPC, I get the following error:

```
Error: There are no 'Public' subnet groups in this VPC. Available types:
at LookedUpVpc.selectSubnetObjectsByType (C:\WebstormProjects\beyond-core\node_modules\aws-cdk-lib\aws-ec2\lib\vpc.js:1:5056)
at LookedUpVpc.selectSubnetObjects (C:\WebstormProjects\beyond-core\node_modules\aws-cdk-lib\aws-ec2\lib\vpc.js:1:3778)
at LookedUpVpc.selectSubnets (C:\WebstormProjects\beyond-core\node_modules\aws-cdk-lib\aws-ec2\lib\vpc.js:1:1500)
at new BaseLoadBalancer (C:\WebstormProjects\beyond-core\node_modules\aws-cdk-lib\aws-elasticloadbalancingv2\lib\shared\base-load-balancer.js:1:2299)      
at new ApplicationLoadBalancer (C:\WebstormProjects\beyond-core\node_modules\aws-cdk-lib\aws-elasticloadbalancingv2\lib\alb\application-load-balancer.js:1:1825)
at new ApplicationLoadBalancedServiceBase (C:\WebstormProjects\beyond-core\node_modules\aws-cdk-lib\aws-ecs-patterns\lib\base\application-load-balanced-service-base.js:1:2716)
at new ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService (C:\WebstormProjects\beyond-core\node_modules\aws-cdk-lib\aws-ecs-patterns\lib\fargate\application-load-balanced-fargate-service.js:1:601)
at new AndoStack (C:\WebstormProjects\beyond-core\services\ando\lib\ando-stack.ts:57:25)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\WebstormProjects\beyond-core\services\ando\bin\ando.ts:10:1)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
```

I have checked the tags and I noticed that I have already updated tags for two different public subnet as follow:

```
aws-cdk:subnet-name Public
aws-cdk:subnet-type Public
```

I did not understand the reason of the error and I hope anyone can help with the issue. Thank you!